# How does Uint16Array UV attribute of BufferGeometry map to texture?

Tags: three.js

I'm accustomed to UV map coordinates in the range from `[0,1]`, however, when inspecting an imported GLTF SkinnedMesh with BufferGeometry, I noticed that the range is a 16-bit unsigned integer (Uint16Array):

[image: screenshot of Uint16Array from Chrome debugger]

What's additionally confusing to me is that the `normalized` attribute is false. According to the docs, it seems like this should be set to `true` if these 16-bit values are normalized to the range [0,1]. And yet the UV texture map is working fine.

How does this UV map work? What is its range?

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the UV Map in Blender:

[image]

Comment: I've discovered by trial and error that the range of this particular UV map is 4096. (The underlying image is 256x256). But I still don't know how to determine the UV range by looking at the properties of the UV attribute alone.

Comment: That's really interesting. I've always seen UVs in the `[0-1]` range. Maybe it's expected to tile the texture? Where did you get the geometry from?

Comment: The geometry is from an FBX imported into Blender, then exported into GLTF format. I use GLTFLoader to load it.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what the UVs look like in [Blender's UV editor](https://media.blendernation.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Screenshot-2019-09-05-at-07.25.40-copy.jpg)? Maybe they are in fact scaled up to go beyond the standard `[0, 1]` range.

Comment: It looks to me like the intention is to tile the texture here. But (if .normalized were true) quantization would also be a reasonable theory, to save a few KB.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I don't think tiling is intended, see screenshot.